# Regularity of a curve with an n-secant line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am working on exercise 5.1 in Eisenbud's Geometry of Syzygies:

Show that if the (reduced and irreducible) curve $X\subset \mathbb{P}^r$ has an $n$-secant line (a line that meets the curve in $n$ points) then $\text{reg}\; \mathcal{I}_X\geq n$.

I read somewhere that $X$ cannot be cut out by hypersurfaces of degree $n-1$ under these conditions. This should be clear to me, but it's not. Also, how does this imply a solution to the exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every form of degree $n-1$ or less which vanishes on $X$, will also vanish on the $n$-secant line (because the restriction to that line is a form of degree $n-1$ or less, with $n$ zeros).

If $X$ is cut out by forms of degree $n-1$, then all of those forms vanish on the line. And the variety defined by those forms, then, includes the line in addition to $X$. This absurdity forces that the ideal of $X$ includes at least one generator of degree $n$ or greater. That, in turn, implies that the ideal of $X$ has regularity at least $n$.